# VBA insert picture and legends word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

A vba script that seems simple but don't work exactly as I want .
My script inserts images ( PNG files) in the current document with a caption after each picture that is the name of the file.

So to insert images I use:

```
Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName: = sFile
Selection.TypeParagraph
```

And to insert text after I use:

```
Set Opar = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add
oPar.Range.Text = sFile
oPar.Range.Style = " Normal"
```

The problem is that images are all found in the beginning of the document , arranged in reverse order (the last image inserted appears first in the document) and legends are all found at the end of the document.

What's happening ?

Comment: Have you tried moving your selection after insertion?

Comment: This not happen to me with your code, but whatever, you can try move the selection first and then reexecute your code like @Cptn_Hammer says.

Comment: Can you explain "move the selection" plz ? Is it done by code ?

Comment: Yes, in your code you can do something like Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory which will move the selection to the end of the document and insert in the right order. Call Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory after each insert.

Comment: here is a code that insert images and captions, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359351/vba-word-add-captions-to-images-add-max-height-criterion

Answer (score 1):

@Boro: It's more efficient to work directly with the object model than trying to coerce Selection (imitating the user actions). There's no single way to achieve what you describe, so I'm going to demonstrate my preference:

```
Dim ils as Word.InlineShape
Dim rng as Word.Range
'Starting with current sel, but this could also be a Range...
Set ils = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName: = sFile)
Set rng = ils.Range
'Move the focus AFTER the picture
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
'new para, text, followed by new para
rng.Text = vbCr & sFile & vbCr
rng.Style = wdStyleNormal
'focus in last para inserted by code
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
'Do other things with the Range...
'Leave cursor there for user to work
rng.Select
```

The key in my approach is *collapsing* the Range, either to the start or end point. Think of it like pressing the left or right arrow key to reduce the selection to a blinking cursor. Except you can have any number of Ranges (but only one Selection) and things won't jump around on the screen.

Comment: This is perfect : bravo ! And thank you for the detailed explanation also. It helps a lot.

Comment: If an answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it. Welcome to Stack Overflow!